# Proving subspace for a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say I have

$V = \mathbb{R}[x] \leq 3 = \{
a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2|a_0,a_1,a_2  \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and I have to show V is a subspace of ℝ[x]. I can do this by showing it fulfills three requirements, but I will only focus on the first

(1) The zero vector 0 $\in$ ℝ[x] is $\in$ U $\subseteq$ ℝ[x]

I can prove that 0 $\in $V $\subseteq $ ℝ[x], by setting $a_0,a_1,a_2$ = 0, in
$a(x) = a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ and then get a(x) = 0.Thereby I have proved (1).

I my proof for (1) correct? My teaching assistant said it could use improvement, but didn't have time to elaborate further.

Comment: It seems correct to me. Since $0=0+0x+0x^2$ and $0+0x+0x^2\in V$, it follows that $0\in V$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct, but it is simpler and more natural to say that the $0$ element of $\Bbb R[x]$ is the null polynomial and that the null polynomial belongs to $\Bbb R[x]_{\leqslant3}$, since its degree is $0$.

Comment: It is unusual to define polynomial degrees in a way that the zero polynomial has degree 0. Instead one either considers deg(0) as undefined or as = - infinity

Comment: @UlysseKeller If the degree of the null polynomial is undefined, then that polynomial does not belong to $\Bbb R[x]_{\leqslant3}$, since this is the set of those polynomials whose degree is smaller than or equal to $3$, right?!

Comment: To avoid that problem, is exactly why deg(0) is better defined as - infinity -> any fixed value < 0 would do, but setting deg(0) to - infinity has the extra advantage to let deg(PQ) = deg(P)+deg(Q) stay true when P or Q  is 0 (here one has the hyp. that the base ring is an integral domain e.g. a field like the f. of real nb.)